# Get Parameters from Current URL in the View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a URL with this structure below.

```
http://localhost:8000/products?category=chairs&sort=name
```

In my view, I inserted the pagination links.

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

However, I need to append the products links the parameters from my URL using this appends method.

```
{{ $products->appends(['sort' => 'name'...])->links() }}
```

An example is in the documentation, but how can I get an array of all the parameters from my current URL that I show above? The final result displayed the category and the current sort.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `request()->input()`.

```
{{ $products->appends(request()->input())->links() }}
```

The above will give you an array of all your inputs.

You could also retrieve a single input:

```
{{ request()->input('sort') }}
```

[input()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L206) also can take two parameters `input($key, $default)`, which means you could do this:

```
{{ request()->input('sort', 'price') }}
```

... and what would happen is, if `sort` is not defined in your request, it will have the value `price`.

The difference between `input()` and `query()` is that `input()` will also work with other HTTP requests type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$query = $request->query();
```

that will return your parameters in an array, like:

`array:2 [▼
  "category" => "chairs"
  "sort" => "name"
]`

and if you want to get a specific name/value, use:

```
$category = $request->query('category');
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input